# Responsive Navbar wont collapse

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, responsive-design

I'm working on a simple website with Bootstrap but I can't put the navbar working on responsive design.
https://www.codeply.com/p/Jsz9jsiAqm
I've searched for solutions, my data-target seems to be just as everybody do and still when I click the button it does nothing.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code had `collaspe` instead of `collapse` in the `data-toggle` attribute.

Here's the updated code :- https://www.codeply.com/p/iowuSN2BGh

Comment: Aw man, it was so simple and I was lost.. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe with the wrapper

```
<div class="d-flex toggled" id="wrapper">
```

and put a script like this

```
$(window).resize(function(e) {
      if($(window).width()<=768){
        $("#wrapper").removeClass("toggled");
      }else{
        $("#wrapper").addClass("toggled");
      }
    });
```

Check this page https://mmenujs.com/docs/wrappers/bootstrap.html